# Are there any linters that can detect when a file extension .tsx/.jsx does not contan any JSX and hence can be .ts/.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Is there any way with linters to pick up when a file has the .tsx/.jsx extension but with no JSX in it? I have seen the inverse of picking up when .ts/.js has JSX in it with the eslint rule below.

```
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }]
}
```

Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a significant benefit to this? Legitimately curious, I wouldn't think there would be any harm in a .jsx file that doesn't strictly need to be .jsx after it's been compiled.

Comment: Honestly this is purely from curiosity and yes I can not state a clear benefit other then the extension of the file giving a clear indication of what it contains.